# I am not able to access account console after adding reverse proxy

Tags: keycloak

I'm a beginner in using Keycloak. After playing with it I decided to add a reverse proxy for ssl, so that I have https connections to keycloak. The problem now is that I can not access the account console (https://localhost/realms/myrealm/account).

I've tried some of the solutions available here(proxy headers, setting PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING to true, etc. ) but with no success. Is there something that I'm missing?

The following is the docker compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres-keycloak:
    image: postgres:15.5-alpine3.18
    volumes:
      - "postgres_keycloak_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: <user>
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: <password>
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"
    networks:
      - keycloak_on_nginx

  keycloak-service:
    #image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0
    build: ./
    command: start --optimized
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: <strong pass>
      KC_PROXY: edge
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres-keycloak/keycloak
      KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_URL: https://localhost:8443
      KC_HOSTNAME_URL: https://localhost:8443
      KC_CACHE_ENABLED: true
    depends_on:
      postgres-keycloak:
        condition: service_healthy
    #restart: always

    networks:
      - keycloak_on_nginx

  
  nginx-keycloak:
    image: nginx:1.24.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/config/keycloak.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./nginx/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt:/etc/nginx/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt
      - ./nginx/certs/nginx-selfsigned.key:/etc/nginx/certs/nginx-selfsigned.key

    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 8443:443
    depends_on:
      - keycloak-service
    networks:
      - keycloak_on_nginx


volumes:
  postgres_keycloak_data:

networks:
  keycloak_on_nginx:
    driver: bridge
```

Here is the Dockerimage for keycloak:

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0 as builder

# Enable health and metrics support
ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true

# Configure a database vendor
ENV KC_DB=postgres

WORKDIR /opt/keycloak
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/


ENV KC_DB=postgres
#ENV KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://keycloak-service/keycloak
ENV KC_DB_USERNAME=admin
ENV KC_DB_PASSWORD=<strong pass>
ENV PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
#ENV KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=https://localhost:8443/auth
#ENV KC_HOSTNAME_URL=https://localhost:8443
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh"]
```

```
events {}

http {

    # Sets the backend server to send traffic to
    upstream keycloakserver {
        # name of the service inside docker compose file
        server keycloak-service:8080;
    }

    # http server block
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name localhost;
        # redirect to https
        return 301 https://localhost:8443$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name localhost;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/nginx-selfsigned.key;


        location / {
            proxy_pass http://keycloakserver;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }

       
    }
}
```

EDIT: Nevermind, I solved it. I have set Web Origins to * on clients: account and account console inside the realm. This solved it for me.